# How should I disable app update popup in ionic 2?

Tags: android, ionic2

I don't have much experience as an ionic 2 developer. I have used [APP update plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-update/) for update but it had been ask popup for update current app. How should I disable update popup? Is it possible to forcefully update ionic 2 app when new version available?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daWjn.png)

Comment: Not able to get your point  , If you want to disable this then remove plugin

Comment: @Anuj I want app update functionality force full without asking any popup. If I remove plugin then How should I update my current APP? Please Provide other solution if you have

Comment: There is no any feature to forcefully update app. In mobile if you already open feature to download it on wifi then it will download. You can do one thing that show popup and then redirect it to playstore to update the app and if user have new app then it will work otherwise it will not work .

Comment: @Anuj : I don't want to use play store because of security reason. Is it possible in android APP?

Comment: Simple Do  : -   If version change show popup and update it .User may not use app if not updated , simpel